# sha256 hash collisions between two strings

Tags: php, encryption, hash, sha256, sha

I have to find two string which are passed in URL as parameter 'str1' and 'str2' and satisfies these conditions ?

```
if($_GET['str1'] !== $_GET['str2'] and $_GET['str1'] and $_GET['str2']) 
{
    $hash1 = hash('sha256', $salt . $_GET['str1']);
    $hash2 = hash('sha256', $salt . $_GET['str2']);

    if($hash1 === $hash2) {
       #print str1 and str2
    }

}
```

How will I find out?

Comment: What?!  I have no idea what you're talking about!

Comment: Have to Find out the str1 and str2 that satisfies the above conditions in url  to print the result , http://httpurl.php?str1=?&str2=?

Comment: You want two strings that is not the same give the same sha hash? Not possible within reasonable timespan to figure that out.

Comment: may be if we try with different data type ? is that possible ?

Comment: As far as I can see, there aren't any known (or at least public) sha256 collisions. Obviously passing the same string twice will satisfy it. Basically, why are you asking? Is it a contest? A thought experiment?

Comment: Why don't you Google "break sha hash" and try and find the solution yourself?

Comment: @iainn no, first line says str1 and str2 is strictly not the same

Comment: @Andreas Yes, apparently I'm blind. The fact that the `and` operator is used instead of `&&` is possibly important as well, given that this sounds like a contest question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only possible solution to break that is to make the hash function not work.
Hash function expects string input (or typecast to string), so making input as array will break the hash and both return false/not working.
Meaning both is strictly the same.

It's a cheat, but it satisfies all parts of the code as it currently is.

```
<?php
$_GET['str1'] = ["a"];
$_GET['str2'] = ["b"];
$salt = "aaabdnelnFnekknfn";

if($_GET['str1'] !== $_GET['str2'] and $_GET['str1'] and $_GET['str2']) 
{
    $hash1 = hash('sha256', $salt . $_GET['str1']);
    $hash2 = hash('sha256', $salt . $_GET['str2']);

    if($hash1 === $hash2) {
       var_dump($_GET['str1'],$_GET['str2']);
    }

}
```

https://3v4l.org/SPYKb

Comment: This is also why you should never use weakly typed languages to implement security systems, in my opinion. If the runtimes accept both text and bytes for the same input parameter then the situation becomes worse. The hash function works correctly in above example; it's the type juggling that is to blame.

Comment: The code is a bit of a cheat. But it can be easily fixed by checking if the inputs are string, if not don't pass then to hash().

Comment: the golden rule of save your ass: always validate user input against type, format, syntax, length, etc.